# What is the best developer toolbar for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, firebug, ie-developer-tools

I use '[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)' extension of FF to debug designed webpages and installed 'IE Developer Toolbar' for IE to get this purpose, but it is not as good as FireBug. It is difficult to work with it.

Are there any other extension for IE that are more user friendly and easy to use??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite/ie.html) for IE  too. Docs [Here](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Comment: Firebug lite gets my vote...big advantage XHR Requests without using Fiddler

Comment: thanks,but FireBug Lite is too slow on my IE.
is it the same on yours??

Comment: Welcome, yeah, its a little bit slow for me too, but I am ok with its that because of its features.

Answer (score 3):

I use IE8's excellent built-in Developer Tools.  Go to Tools > Developer Tools or just press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Excellent is a very strong word...  I'd go for 'nearly adequate'

Comment: @daddywoodland: ...excellent relative to any of the other options for IE in 2010.